# Check when a Program is Done Running using a .BAT

Tags: windows, process, batch-file

How would I go about checking to see if a specific program is done running?

I'm attempting to make a script that runs a series of .exe's (specifically and setup program and a number of patches) in order automatically.

So far I've been able to get them to run at the same time, but that's obviously not what I need.

How can I get them to run each after the other is completed?

I've looked at a few already posted, but I wasn't able to modify them to what I need.

Comment: post an example of what you're doing.  A BAT file shouldn't default to launching an executable in a new thread.

Answer (score 2):

Run your exe from the bat using this syntax

```
start /wait foo.exe
```

to wait for the executable to return before continuing on in the bat file.

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify what method are you using for running the programs?
There are more than one.

For instance, if you are using "START", there's a "/WAIT" switch which takes care of the waiting.

Comment: I'm currently using run, or just the filename on the line. I tried start, but it basically brought up command prompt with the directory where the .bat was run from.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the right parameters to START?

It should be used like this:

    START "Window Title" /WAIT "Path\to\my.exe" "my exe parameter" "or parameters"

with an optional /Dpath to set the starting directory for you exe.

Comment: Eww, that was my first comment. Didn't realise I wouldn't get formatting, sorry. Important part: from START "Window Title" to \my.exe".

Comment: Ah, ok. I was unaware that I needed a window title. 

I'm also using Vista if that matters.

Comment: You do not need to specify a window title to use the start command.  You should edit your original question and give more details about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: The wierd thing is though, it works fine when I have an extra parameter with a window title. When I take it away it stops working.

Comment: Which brings us back to my first comment: use the window title parameter and you're good. :)